# How to sequentially publish messages in pubnub?

Tags: reactjs, sockets, asynchronous, async-await, pubnub

So the question is how to send messages in pubnub sequentially.

Example: I add text and 2 images. Flow should be like => send text as 1st message, send first image as 2nd message and send second image as 3nd message. They should appear in pubnub history one by one.

Let`s say I have all this stuff in **sendArray** variable

```
(async () => {
  for await (const item of sendArray) {
    pubnub.publish({ 
      channel: currentChannel, 
      message: item, 
    })
  }
})();
```

I`ve tried something like this, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost correct, just a wrong placement of the `await` keyword.

```
(async () => {
  for (const item of sendArray) {
    await pubnub.publish({ 
      channel: currentChannel, 
      message: item, 
    })
  }
})();
```

This is because the publish method is an async operation that you need to await. `for await` is a special construct for iterating async iterables so there is no need to use it here. For loop respects the await keyword inside async blocks.

Comment: Just to be clear, just because you publish "message 1" synchronously before "message 2", there is no absolute guarantee that they arrive on the client subscriber in that order because the PubNub network is not stateful from one publish to the next (even from the same publisher) and is asynchronous by necessity. However, it is very highly likely that the messages will arrive in the order they were sent. It should be close to 0 that you get out-of-order messages arriving that originated from the same publisher unless the publish rate is high and sustained for long period of time and sent async.